# Retrieving everything after certain part of column by using field calculator in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, field-calculator, python-parser

I have a column in an attribute table and I want to split it with the field-calculator in arcis in a way that I get everything after the 4th blank (space) in a new column:

[image]

I tried it by using `!Kreuzungsname!.split(" ")[4]+!Kreuzungsname!.split(" ")[5]` in the field calculator, but the problem is that some of the entries only contain 4 and not 5 blanks.

Is there a way to get everything after the 4th blank?

Answer (score 4):

with python, you can do this:

```
" ".join(!kreusungname!.split(" ")[4:])
```

split to create a list, take elements from 5 to the end, and join back with a space between.

Comment: More generally you might want to take a look at list slicing notation in python. That's how you you say "items M through N" rather than accessing individual items one at a time. The accepted answer by Greg Hewgill in this StackExchange post gives a pretty good overview. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation